# extension of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to extend the function $f$ continuously at $z_0=0$, where $f$:

$f(z)= \dfrac{Re(z) Im(z)}{|z|^2}$

so I'm doing z=x+iy, and calculating the limit

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$

at this point I'm having trouble determining if the limit exists

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Set $y=ax$ and see what happens with your limit.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I have tried using the diagonal lines $x,x$ and $x,-x$. But I'm not sure how to interpret the result

Comment: Which limits did you get along those diagonals?

Comment: Have you also tried the straight lines parallel to the axes?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was a bit confused, but now using x,x and x,-x. I got 1/2 and -1/2 respectively